# Loading a non typed lib into Electron + React + Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron, electron-forge, annotorious

I created a react app with create-react-app. In this app, I use Openseadragon to display images. Furthermore, I use the Annotorious plugin to annotate the image. My code runs without any errors. Since Annotorious has no type definitions, I imported it like this:

```
import OpenSeadragon from "openseadragon";
//@ts-ignore
import * as Annotorious from "@recogito/annotorious-openseadragon";
import "@recogito/annotorious-openseadragon/dist/annotorious.min.css";
```

Now I wanted to package the app in electron forge. To save me some config work, I just used the electron forge [template for typescript-webpack](https://www.electronforge.io/templates/typescript-+-webpack-template), [did all react steps](https://www.electronforge.io/guides/framework-integration/react-with-typescript), and then copied the cra code over to the forge project.

However, now this exact code does not work. As soon as I call the Annotorius code, I get this error:

```
Annotorious is not a function TypeError: Annotorious is not a function
    at Object.eval [as handler] (webpack-internal:///./src/frontend/elements/openSeaDragon/OpenSeaDragonViewer.tsx:75:32)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/openseadragon/build/openseadragon/openseadragon.js:3225:33)
    at $.Viewer.raiseEvent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/openseadragon/build/openseadragon/openseadragon.js:3247:13)
    at checkCompletion (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/openseadragon/build/openseadragon/openseadragon.js:8239:27)
    at options.success (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/openseadragon/build/openseadragon/openseadragon.js:8291:17)
    at processReadyItems (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/openseadragon/build/openseadragon/openseadragon.js:9195:39)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/openseadragon/build/openseadragon/openseadragon.js:9207:13)
    at $.TileSource.success (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/openseadragon/build/openseadragon/openseadragon.js:10102:21)
    at Object.eval [as handler] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/openseadragon/build/openseadragon/openseadragon.js:12640:19)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/openseadragon/build/openseadragon/openseadragon.js:3225:33)
```

OpenSeadragon throws the error because I attach Annotorious in the "open" event of OpenSeadragon.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68993573/cannot-find-name-annotorious) about Annotorious in combination with next.js, but I could use the answer.

If this error is caused by the way I import the app (maybe Annotorious is not present for Openseadragon), then here is my code how I load the app. I import the `Index.tsx` in the `renderer.ts`, and everything is loaded:

**renderer.ts:**

```
import "./index"
```

I'm very new to electron, so if you need more information, please add a comment, and I will add it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this combination, so I can't be of help. I've added the Annotorious tag in case that helps though. You can only have 5 tags, so I've removed the OpenSeadragon one... Feel free to shuffle them around however you want.